# Editor and Inplace issues

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have an issue with inplace with Editor i.e the rich text editor.

1. When a user stores html text with editor (the rich text editor), the text is escaped in the inplace label.
   How do I set escape to false in the inplace so it does not escape html. Which is the point of the rich text editor in the first place.
2. The second issue is that when I try to save the editor.the next time the inplace label is clicked , the editor ( the rich text editor) disappears.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. The point of [rich text editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_rich-text_editor) is that it provides simple tools for users to format their text without *direct* markup. This is the reason why your markup is escaped. The component you need is [codeMirror](http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-mojarra/views/codeMirror.jsf) from primefaces-extensions which is a simple code-editor interface for javascript, html, etc.
2. I was able to reproduce this behavior. You should take a look to [primefaces bug tracker](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/list) and report this issue.

Comment: I looked at codeMirror.Sadly , it does not fulfil my requirements. I what my users to use a rich text editor to format text not code like writing a normal word document .That is what the <p:editor /> primefaces compument is for if I am not mistaken. Anyway,

Comment: now if for example someone writes this. "I am a <strong>boy </strong>".formating it with <strong> and saves it should save it then saves the html.When the data comes back from the DB. it comes back as "I am a <strong>boy </strong>" instead it formatted .becos the html has been escaped. The problem is that I do not want the html escaped when it is returning from the db. So how do I escape html in The inplace like how it is done in <h:outputText escape="false"/> ??

Comment: Somebody crated a patch where you can specify your output and input elements through facets. [Feature suggestion for p:inplace: output component facet](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4330). Seems there is no official support to have separate output/input components for p:inplace. Hope this helps.

Comment: @akoskm As you pointed out, I've created a patch. However it has some quirks regarding the editor element.It seems to update the editor upon clicking cancel. This makes the editor unusable. A workaround for this is to update the editor upon opening the editor.

Comment: @akoskm: that was helpful. At least my issues are half solved.